# What type of operation should you use on single expressions containing vectors and numbers in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to produce a contour plot of the following equation in Matlab.

```
theta=[(k+0.5)^2+t^2]^(-1/2)-[(k-0.5)^2+t^2]^(-1/2).
```

This is how I initially expressed it.

```
k=linspace(-1,1,20); 
t=linspace(-0.5,0.5,20); 
[K,T]=meshgrid(k,t);
Z=((K+0.5)^2+T.^2)^-0.5 -((K-0.5)^2+T.^2)^-0.5;
contour(K,T,Z, 'ShowText', 'on')
```

I'm getting the error message 'Input arguments for contour must be real.' so assuming I have expressed the equation wrong in the 4th line. I'm confused as to what type of operation I should use for expressions such as (K+0.5)^2+T.^2, where there are both vectors and numbers. How should I express it in Matlab syntax?
Apologies if the question is really basic. Absolute beginner.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate error is because `Z` contains complex values (has non-zero imaginary components).

The *real* issue though is that you have used the [matrix power (`^`)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mpower.html) rather than an [element-wise power (`.^`)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/power.html) in some places in your definition of `Z`.

Your expression to compute `Z` should actually be:

```
Z = ((K + 0.5).^2 + T.^2).^-0.5 - ((K - 0.5).^2 + T.^2).^-0.5;
```

[image]